# What is mail_max_use_rip_connection and where is it set?

Tags: postfix, dovecot

When trying to configure an IMAP client to connect on 993 to a Postfix/Dovecot server I just deployed, i get an occasional timeout sometimes with a message about  mail_max_use_rip_connection = 10. I'm guessing i should increase the value by a few and see if the error keeps up but I cant find where this parameter is set.  Anyone have any ideas bout this?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you searching for `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and `/etc/postfix/master.cf`?

Answer (score 0):

The file you search for is `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` (or `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-imap.conf`) and the proper name of the parameter is `mail_max_userip_connections`. The config setting should look like:

```
protocol imap {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 20
}
```